# Persist an Entity in a Transactional Context in a ForEach (Spring MVC + JPA)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I am using Spring MVC and JPA, and I don't know how persist an Entity without it being updated in the ForEach.

```
@Transactional
public void save(House house, List<Long> room) {        
    for (Long id : room) {
        house.setRoom(new Room(id));
        houseDao.save(house);
    }
}

public void save(House house) {
    entityManager.persist(house);
}
```

I would like in each tie of the loop persist a new object that would change only the information of the room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming House has a Set / List of rooms.

Is the CascadeType.PERSIST already defined for the rooms in House class?

```
class House {
      @OneToMany(mappedBy = "whatever", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
    private List<Room> rooms;
}
```

So now your code becomes:

```
@Transactional
public void save(House house, List<Long> room) {        
    for (Long id : room) {
        house.getRooms().add(new Room(id));
    }
    houseDao.save(house);

}

public void save(House house) {
    entityManager.persist(house);
}
```